# special counsel indictments

Tags: immigration, citizenship, identity-theft

Sixteen counts of conspiracy to defraud the US Government https://www.justice.gov/usam/criminal-resource-manual-923-18-usc-371-conspiracy-defraud-us by obstructing official activities of the DOJ and the FEC were recently released by the Special Counsel Robert Mueller against Russian citizens, whom apparently used identity theft and basic impersonation and wire fraud to obtain funds and promote a particular political candidate.

Are individuals who illegally enter the U.S. and obtain the most basic funding and use it to promote a political agenda able to be prosecuted under the same legal theory?

Can millions of these individuals be indicted?

Because they benefit from a perceived relaxation in the enforcement of immigration laws and obtain access to public benefits, can they be implicated in a conspiracy to defraud and obstruct the FEC?

Comment: I cleaned up your question by removing the falsehoods and foolishness.

Comment: @A.fm. but you've also changed the question so that it is asking about different specific acts.

Comment: I don't think I did. The question was whether illegal aliens can be prosecuted for conspiracy because they (according to OP, but not really) steal identities to vote and whatnot.

Comment: I think my examples and nomenclature help to elucidate the actual problem we face.

Comment: Your legal question is buried under your political agenda.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I guess but I am trying hard to find a fair way to apply the law; can it not be said that illegal aliens in this country are supporting a political candidate and committing overt acts by demonstrating at various rallies?; can it not be said that these individuals represent, have strong financial, cultural, political ties with foreign sovereign nations? It sounds like the same case to me, except the only one that was brought was one that, as you say, is mired in politics.

Comment: Obviously they don't have strong financial or political ties, since they've had to emigrate illegally. It could be said that a lot of people are supporting a lot of things, but that has no relevance to how they came to be present, unless you already have evidence of a conspiracy, in which case that stands alone. None of this question makes sense unless you're trying to bend things to a political bias and ignoring how the world works.

Comment: @Nij I just find the similarities too coincidental to ignore.  A foreign citizen subverts a Social Security process, violates naturalization laws, accepts government benefits, earns untaxed unreported income and then proceeds to commit an overt act in support of a political candidate.  How are they not next on the list to indict?

Comment: There are plenty of animals with four hooved legs, long faces and swishy tails to consider before you jump to unicorns. Stop looking for giant conspiracies and accept that maybe in a country of 330 million, coincidence is all but certain to happen.

Comment: you just can't explain it away, all these things i mentioned are directly associated with a charge of conspiracy to defraud the us government, accepting money and then spending it on any kind of political rally is a direct violation of the 'obstruction of fec' part, especially if you are not a citizen, you must register as a foreign contributor. it's exactly the same. and somebody  probably needs to investigate whether somebody other than cloak and dagger 'Russian nationals' are doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Not to legitimize your misinformation, but the main difference is illegal immigration doesn't fall under that statute, which is meant to protect the integrity of government functions. There is an entire body of law related to immigration and, although mentioning immigration is simply a useful distraction from the Russia issue, immigration offenses nonetheless do count as RICO predicate offenses and so the conspiracy angle is covered. Illegal Immigration Reform & Immigrant Responsibility Act, esp. 18 USC §1015(e) - felony to make a false claim of citizenship to obtain fed benefits and/or vote

Comment: To be clear, nothing about being an illegal immigrant has anything to do with conspiracy. The notion that millions of people could be indicted for a conspiracy is laughable. RICO charges have to do with an ongoing criminal enterprise.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch "_political agenda_" Someone's "political agenda" is another person's obvious truths.

Comment: @A.fm. "_The notion that millions of people could be indicted for a conspiracy is laughable_" So is Mueller's notion that political interference is only OK with the US does it abroad.

Comment: @curiousguy nope.........

Comment: @A.fm. Why would the US be allowed to influence public debates and even election abroad while denying that right to foreigners or imposing the (unclear, impossible to understand) FEC rules on Russians?

Answer (score 3):

> Can millions of these individuals be indicted?

Yes, they can indicted. Anyone (as an individual or a group who conspires) who commits a crime can be indicted. (But, it's a fantasy to think that millions would be indicted as part of a conspiracy.)

The reason many people are not indicted for crimes is because they are not caught by law enforcement (LE) or because of the lack of the sheer numbers of LE required to pursue all criminals. And, if criminals are caught, the reason they may or may not be indicted is either prosecutorial discretion, i.e., a prosecutor decides not to indict because the crime isn't very serious. Or, probably much more relevant, is that there simply are not enough personnel in a county or state attorney's office to prosecute everyone who could be indicted. Prosecutors must oftentimes make decisions on who to indict and consider their available time, the seriousness of the crime, the available evidence and the possibilities of the success of their indictments.

And, of course, politics sometimes comes into play; prosecutors may or may not pursue indictments because of political expediency, i.e. deporting an model citizen who also happens to be in the country illegally. But political pressure can work both ways, for and against prosecutorial discretion. Depending on your persuasion, it's either a bug or a feature in our legal system. But political influence and public opinion can also lead to changes in the legal system, as it is the representational branch of our governmental system that legislates the laws that the judicial system uses and enforces. If enough criminals are not indicted for a particular crime, and social or political pressure comes to bear, chances are good the legislative branch will take action. That's the way the system works.

Comment: Ok, I guess this is a good answer, something like is jaywalking a crime or what is the official mean look under UCMJ but I'm looking for more details and precedent.  Is there any research you can reference to support these claims that prosecutor discretion and political expediency play a role?  I have one for you, US vs Internet Research Assoc District of Columbia 2018. Can you tell me how that case reflects prosecutor discretion and political expediency?

Comment: The leading case on prosecutorial discretion is *Castle Rock v. Gonzalez* 545 U.S. 748 (2004).

Comment: @ohwilleke wow yeah hard to find a TOTALLY unrelated case based on the broad spectrum and etymology of this line of law but yeah you managed it gold star